# Jsoup: parse url links separately

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I use jsoup to parse all url links from a **content** string, which is working well.

Part of the content string with the urls, as you see the links are presented after the text "Download Instructions:", "Mirror:" and "Additional:":

```
<u>Download Instructions:</u><br/>
<a class="postlink" href="https://test.com/info">https://test.com/info</a>
<br/>Mirror:<br/>
<a class="postlink" href="http://global.eu/navi.html">http://global.eu/navi.html</a>
<br/>Additional:<br/>
<a class="postlink" href="http://main.org/navi.html">http://main.org/navi.html</a>
```

Now my goal is to parser all urls (can be multiple) after the text **"Download Instructions:"** and the text **"Mirror:"** **separately**, urls after "Additional" should be ignored.

Below code piece only parses them all and adds them to a (url) arraylist.

```
int j = 0;
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
Elements links = doc.select("a.postlink");
for (Element el : links) {
    String urlman = el.attr("abs:href");
    if (urlman != null) {
        url.add(j, urlman);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Would be great if somebody could assist.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your posted structure you can check the previous sibling nodes to find the node (here either `#text` or the `<u>` tag) which describes the anchors. Then simply do some form of String comparison.

**Example Code**

```
String source = "<u>Download Instructions:</u><br/><a class=\"postlink\" href=\"https://1test.com/info\">https://test.com/info</a><br/><a class=\"postlink\" href=\"https://2test.com/info\">https://test.com/info</a><br/><a class=\"postlink\" href=\"https://3test.com/info\">https://test.com/info</a><br/>Mirror:<br/><a class=\"postlink\" href=\"http://global.eu/navi1.html\">http://global.eu/navi.html</a><br/><a class=\"postlink\" href=\"http://global.eu/navi2.html\">http://global.eu/navi.html</a><br/>Additional:<br/><a class=\"postlink\" href=\"http://main.org/navi.html\">http://main.org/navi.html</a>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(source, "UTF-8");

List<String> downloadInstructionsUrls = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> mirrorUrls = new ArrayList<>();

for (Element el : doc.select("a.postlink")) {
    Node previousSibling = el.previousSibling();

    while( !(previousSibling.nodeName().equals("u") || previousSibling.nodeName().equals("#text")) ){
        previousSibling = previousSibling.previousSibling();
    }

    String identifier = previousSibling.toString();

    if(identifier.contains("Download Instructions")){
        downloadInstructionsUrls.add(el.attr("abs:href"));
    }else if(identifier.toString().contains("Mirror")){
        mirrorUrls.add(el.attr("abs:href"));
    }
}

System.out.println("Url for download instructions:");
downloadInstructionsUrls.forEach(url -> {System.out.println("\t"+url);});
System.out.println("Url for mirror:");
mirrorUrls.forEach(url -> {System.out.println("\t"+url);});
```

**Output**

```
Url for download instructions:
    https://1test.com/info
    https://2test.com/info
    https://3test.com/info
Url for mirror:
    http://global.eu/navi1.html
    http://global.eu/navi2.html
```

Comment: @Simon The part "can be multiple" is not yet met, will post an update in a minute or two.

Comment: Thx in advance.

Comment: Hi Frederic, hope you`re fine. I got 1 problem, the download and mirror links are being added "multiple" times to their arraylists. Is it possible to get this fixed?

Comment: @Simon That is a bit too general, since only a part of the source document is known. You could do: `if(!downloadInstructionsUrls.contains(el.attr("abs:href"))) downloadInstructionsUrls.add(el.attr("abs:href"));`